# Extracting 2 D from 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 3D arrays of the form (1000, 1000, 20).
The last dimension, 13, is an index through time stamps.
I want to step through the arrays by time stamps and compare arrays.
Suppose I have A (1000, 1000, 20) and B(1000, 1000, 20).

I want something like

```
for t in range(0,21):   
     asub = A[,,t]  
     bsub = B[,,t]  
     #compare asub and bsub
```

However, that syntax does not seem to work.  how can I do this?

Comment: `A[:,:,t]` ....?

Comment: also `range(20)` if shape is `(1000, 1000, 20)`

Comment: Coldspeed, I think that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### From [the `documentation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing), you need to *"Combine advanced and basic indexing"*.

So *advanced* `indexing` involves `indexing` specific `axis` of an `array`.

For example, taking the `elements` from `index` `1` onwards:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> a[1:, 1:]
array([[5, 6],
       [8, 9]])
```

So if you want to get the `element` from the third `axis` at `index` `t`, you need to select all the `elements` from the other `axis` with just a regular colon (`:`) and then specify `t` for the last `index`:

So you want to do:

```
A[:, :, t]
```